# How do load balancers actually work on the socket/tcp level?

Tags: load-balancing

I can't find information about this and everything I found is related to algorithms, healthy instances, etc, etc. all high level details..

When a load balancer receives a request, does it  simply redirect the user to another IP (similar to HTTP 304 moved) or does it act more as a proxy and create a socket/remote connection to the IP itself?

Thanks, I think I understand better now, so using your terminology is
pass through the same as how a proxy works and redirect would be termination?

Sorry for any "HTTP" confusion, I was trying to use that as an example. but focusing on just TCP (layer 4?) side

If I used termination, then connecting to computer 1.2.3.4 would 
redirect me to a healthy instance IP of 4.5.6.7, and the computer
would have nothing more to do with 1.2.3.4?

and pass through, would keep the connection and use
bandwidth from both servers show the load balancer's IP, etc. and act as the middle man?

Comment: Excellent question, one even I want to know an answer to.

Answer (score 2):

The HTTP redirection is an *application layer* (L7) feature, whereas TCP load balancing works on *transport layer* (L4), not having such features. All the packets goes through the load balancer, which has two options:

- **Pass Through**: Just forward the packets to one of the backends and let it handle the connection.
- **Termination**: Establish separate connections with the client and with one of the backend servers.